# Inheritance calling

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Here's my homework assignment:

> The first part of the problem is to define the subclass `Worker` that inherits from `Employee` and includes an attribute that refers to another employee who is the worker's manager. You should define a method `get_manager` that returns the workers' manager.
>
> Example:
>   `worker = Worker("Fred", 52000, myboss)`
>
> The second part of the problem is to define the subclass `Executive` that inherits from `Employee` and includes an attribute that refers to the yearly bonus.
>
> You should override the wage method to compute executive pay based on his/her salary and bonus. You should use the wage method of `Employee` in the definition of the wage method for the `Executive` class.
>
> Example:
>   `executive = Executive("Kerry", 520000, 1040000)`

I submitted the following code, but I was told “you got the wrong wage for an executive”. I can't see what the error is. How do I make it right?

```
class Employee(object):

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self._name = name
        self._salary = salary

    def my_name(self):
        return self._name

    def wage(self):
        return self._salary/26   # fortnight pay

class Worker(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, salary, manager):
        Employee.__init__(self, name, salary)
        self._manager = manager

    def getManager(self):
        return self._manager

class Executive(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, wage, yearlyBonus):
        Employee.__init__(self, name, salary) 
        self._yearlyBonus = yearlyBonus

    def wage(self):
        return Employee.wage(self)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) to call the superclass of the current class:

```
def __init__(self, name, salary, manager):
    super(Worker, self).__init__(name, salary)
    self._manager = manager
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do use:

```
class Worker(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, salary, manager):
        Employee.__init__(self, name, salary)
        self._manager = manager
```

This will also work on old-style classes, if you happen to inherit one.

Comment: that worked but i got this the wage method of Executive should call the wage method of Employee instead now. i tried Employee.wage(self) but the comment is the same. help please

Answer (score 0):

The two approaches `super(parent, self).method(...)` approach or the `parent.method(self,...)` are roughly equivalent. In both cases, it allows you to call a `method` from the parent and applies it to the child.

This method can be `__init__`: it's always a good idea to initialize a child instance like its parent:

```
class Worker(Employee):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Employee.__init__(self, ...)
        finish_the_initialization_of_worker
```

but the method can be anything, like, `wage`

```
class Executive(Employee):
    def wage(self):
        return Employee.wage(self) + self._yearly_bonus
```

Comment: def wage(self): 
       return Employee.wage(self)
but i got you got the wrong wage for an executive.